# C++ Processing Hog

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++ (not new to programming) and have been working with Google Code Jam problems. I solved the problem [(Alien Language)](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/90101/dashboard) correctly in both Python (my most experienced language) and C++ following the same algorithm. In my experience c++ is much faster than python for many obvious reasons; however, my python version executed ~100x faster than my c++ version. Processing was the limiting factor. I am obviously doing something very wrong I just don't know what it is. Before taking more elaborate measures to find the resource hog I thought I would ask here as this seems to be a very simple solution to someone with c++ experience to point out a resource or method in my code that is inefficient. I am running a unix environment.

I will post my c++ code below. If anyone thinks seeing my python code would help them answer my question I will be happy to post it as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main () 
{
    int L, D, N;

    std::cin >> L;
    std::cin >> D;
    std::cin >> N;
    std::cin.ignore();

    std::string dictionary [D];
    for (int i=0; i<D; i++) {
        std::getline(std::cin, dictionary[i]);
    }   

    for (int tt=1; tt<=N; tt++) {
        std::cerr << tt << std::endl;

        std::string case_word;
        std::getline(std::cin, case_word);

        int current_letter = 0;

        std::vector <int> invalid_indexes;

        while (case_word.length() > 0) {
            std::vector <char> required_letters;
            if (case_word[0] != '(') {
                required_letters.push_back(case_word[0]);
                case_word.erase(case_word.begin());
            }   

            else {
                std::string::iterator closing_parenthesis = std::find(case_word.begin(), case_word.end(), ')');
                std::string::iterator p = case_word.begin()+1;
                while (p != closing_parenthesis) {
                    required_letters.push_back(*(p++));
                }   
                case_word.erase(case_word.begin(), closing_parenthesis+1);
            }   

            for (int dictionary_word=0; dictionary_word<D; dictionary_word++) {
                if (std::find(invalid_indexes.begin(), invalid_indexes.end(), dictionary_word) != invalid_indexes.end()) {
                    continue;                         
                }   
                if (std::find(required_letters.begin(), required_letters.end(), dictionary[dictionary_word][current_letter]) == required_letters.end()) {
                    invalid_indexes.push_back(dictionary_word);
                }   
            }   

            current_letter++;
        }
        std::cout << "Case #" << tt << ": " << D - invalid_indexes.size() << std::endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What was the code jam problem? link...?

Comment: @Ben my apologies. I just fixed it

Comment: No worries! So to start with, it looks like you are using a vector with lots of `insert` and `erase` operations. You should consider using a `map` which has faster insert erase properties and substantially faster searching.

Comment: Okay! I'll try adjusting my code. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Note that VLAs are non-standard, although I doubt that's an issue here.

Comment: There is no need to keep erasing parts of `case_word`. Just maintain an iterator and keep going forward as needed.

Comment: Are you referring to the string or the vector for the VLA? And thank you for the iterator suggestion!

Comment: I dont believe any compiler options are being used. I compiled with `g++ code.cpp'

Comment: @CorbinMc I'm referring to `std::string dictionary[D];`

Comment: Try compiling with `g++ -O2 code.cpp`, and you will probably see some improvement in speed too. But using `map` instead of `vector` will definitely improve things.

Comment: compiling with -O2 sped up the execution by about 5x! thank you so much!

Comment: @CorbinMc 1. it makes no sense to compile without optimisations in C++. The standard library and other libraries rely *heavily* on the presence of an optimiser to work even moderately efficiently. They can do so, because many optimisations can be performed trivially. 2. Always compile with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`. The first option will notify you of non-standard (= illegal) C++ code, the two latter options will inform you of many additional gotchas.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my pass through your code. There is probably some fancy DFA that could be built from the dictionary to speed up the algorithm entirely. This is just an attempt to speed up the algorithm you have with better data structures.

```
for (int tt=1; tt<=N; tt++) {
    std::cerr << tt << std::endl;

    std::string case_word;
    std::getline(std::cin, case_word);

    int current_letter = 0;
    std::string::iterator i = case_word.begin();
```

Switch the code to iterate over `case_word` to avoid expense of erasure of data from the front.

```
    std::tr1::unordered_set<int> invalid_indexes(D);

    while (i != case_word.end()) {
        std::tr1::unordered_set<char> required_letters(256);
```

Use an unordered set for more efficient index lookup. (The `tr1` namespace is because I compiled without enabling C++11).

```
        if (*i != '(') {
            required_letters.insert(*i);
            ++i;
        }

        else {
            std::string::iterator closing_parenthesis
                = std::find(i, case_word.end(), ')');
            std::string::iterator p = i+1;
            while (p != closing_parenthesis) {
                required_letters.insert(*(p++));
            }
            i = closing_parenthesis+1;
        }

        for (int dictionary_word=0; dictionary_word<D; dictionary_word++) {
            int index = dictionary_word;
            if (invalid_indexes.find(index) != invalid_indexes.end()) {
                continue;
            }
            char letter = dictionary[index][current_letter];
            if (required_letters.find(letter) == required_letters.end()) {
                invalid_indexes.insert(dictionary_word);
            }
```

Notice the simplified (and faster) searching that results from using `unordered_set`.

```
        }

        current_letter++;
    }
    std::cout << "Case #" << tt
              << ": " << D - invalid_indexes.size()
              << std::endl;
}
```